# How to use android:onClick?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm new to android programming. How do you use android:onClick? Where do I put the method I want to call?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="doSomething"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/molecule" />
```

Would I put it in the .java file that calls for this layout to be made?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need to put it in the activity class where you setContentView this layout.
The method for the onclick should be in the form of this:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you worked out how to set the content in your activity? In that same activity, add:

```
public void doSomething( View view ) {
    // onClick code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have that worked out how to set the content. Thank you for your response. It was helpful.